# Integrating AWS Lex with Viber

Tags: amazon-lex, viber-bot

I am exploring for possibilities for integrating Viber and Lex. Is there any possibility of integrating AWS-Lex with Viber?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Viber's REST API will assist you in building a solution to integrate the two technologies.

On a high-level, you will need to perform the following steps:-

- Create and publish an Amazon Lex bot
- Create and publish an API that will receive incoming events from Viber
- Create a Viber account
- Configure the Viber account to send events to your published API
- Write a Lambda function to receive the Viber events, call Lex using the relevant bits of data from the Viber event, use the Lex response to send an appropriate response to Viber

This is more or less the same strategy that you can use for connecting any other messaging service with Amazon Lex.

[Viber Rest API](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/)